# Hiding a text value in one list while displaying its value in another using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add one list item from one list to another list. I'm trying to accomplish this by hovering over each individual list item and displaying an 'Add to Cart' button. My code is currently set up in such a way that if I press 'Add to Cart' on any items in the left list every single item will be added to the right list when only the item that was selected should.

Here's the current piece of code I'm using to grab the text and display it in the other list. I'm trying to figure out what to change here to display only the one list item.

```
$(".items").on("click", ".add-to-cart", function (){
    $(".cart-items").children(".cart").addClass("cart-show");
});
```

Here's a fiddle of the entire code:
http://jsfiddle.net/msbpo5yg/

Comment: i think you should copy the element to `my cart` only on click of `add to cart` not `add`. also this code `$(".cart-items").children(".cart").addClass("cart-show");` will get all elements which has class `cart` inside `.cart-items` and add `cart-show` css to it. You can compare the contents inside the elements and add class

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to

```
$(".items").on("click", ".add-to-cart", function (){
    $(".cart-items").children('.cart').eq($(this).closest('.list').index()).addClass("cart-show");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msbpo5yg/4/

Comment: thanks for the help this does exactly what I needed to get done

Answer (score 1):

You can also try few more changes like

```js
$(function () {

    // ADD ITEMS TO LIST BY PRESSING ENTER
    $("input[name='list-name']").keydown(function (e) {
        /*
  var key = e.which;
  if(key === 13) {
   //alert("made it here too");
   //event.preventDefault();
   $("input[name='list-button']").click();
  }
 */
    });

    $(".button-input").click(function () {
        var listInput = $("input[name='list-name']").val().trim();
        //console.log(listInput);
        if (listInput === "") {
            alert("Enter a list item.");
        } else {
            // APPEND NEW LIST ITEMS TO THE LIST
            var addBtn = "<span class='btns'><span class='add-to-cart'>Add to Cart</span>";
            var removeBtn = "<span class='remove-from-list'>Remove</span></span><br>";
            var eachListItem = "<span class='list-items'>" + listInput + "</span><br>";
            var listItem = "<p class='list'>" + eachListItem + " " + addBtn + " " + removeBtn + "</p>";
            $(".items").append(listItem);
            $("input[name='list-name']").val("").focus();
        }
    });

    // ADD ITEMS TO MY CART SIDE/MY LIST SIDE
    $(".items").on("click", ".add-to-cart", function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $list = $this.closest('.list');
        $("<p class='cart cart-show'></p>").html($list.find('.list-items').clone()).appendTo('.cart-items');
        $list.addClass('added');
    });

    $(".items").on("click", ".remove-from-list", function () {
        $(this).closest(".list").remove();
    });

    // SHOW/HIDE THE BUTTONS PER ITEM ADDED
    $(".items").on("mouseenter", ".list:not(.added)", function () {
        $(this).children(".btns").addClass("btns-show");
    });
    $(".items").on("mouseleave", ".list", function () {
        $(this).children(".btns").removeClass("btns-show");
    });

    // DELETE THE ITEMS IN MY LIST SIDE
    $(".items-list").on("click", ".remove-from-list", function () {
        $(this).closest(".list").remove();
    });

    // CLEAR CART LIST
    $(".remove-from-cart").click(function () {
        $(".cart-items").empty();
        $('.items .list.added').removeClass('added')
    });
});
```

```css
/*! normalize.css v3.0.2 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

/**
 * 1. Set default font family to sans-serif.
 * 2. Prevent iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling
 *    user zoom.
 */
 html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    /* 1 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    /* 2 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Remove default margin.
 */
 body {
    margin: 0;
}
/* HTML5 display definitions
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct `block` display not defined for any HTML5 element in IE 8/9.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `details` or `summary` in IE 10/11
 * and Firefox.
 * Correct `block` display not defined for `main` in IE 11.
 */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
/**
 * 1. Correct `inline-block` display not defined in IE 8/9.
 * 2. Normalize vertical alignment of `progress` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */
 audio, canvas, progress, video {
    display: inline-block;
    /* 1 */
    vertical-align: baseline;
    /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Prevent modern browsers from displaying `audio` without controls.
 * Remove excess height in iOS 5 devices.
 */
 audio:not([controls]) {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
}
/**
 * Address `[hidden]` styling not present in IE 8/9/10.
 * Hide the `template` element in IE 8/9/11, Safari, and Firefox < 22.
 */
[hidden], template {
    display: none;
}
/* Links
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the gray background color from active links in IE 10.
 */
 a {
    background-color: transparent;
}
/**
 * Improve readability when focused and also mouse hovered in all browsers.
 */
 a:active, a:hover {
    outline: 0;
}
/* Text-level semantics
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9/10/11, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
 abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}
/**
 * Address style set to `bolder` in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
 b, strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
/**
 * Address styling not present in Safari and Chrome.
 */
 dfn {
    font-style: italic;
}
/**
 * Address variable `h1` font-size and margin within `section` and `article`
 * contexts in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
 h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}
/**
 * Address styling not present in IE 8/9.
 */
 mark {
    background: #ff0;
    color: #000;
}
/**
 * Address inconsistent and variable font size in all browsers.
 */
 small {
    font-size: 80%;
}
/**
 * Prevent `sub` and `sup` affecting `line-height` in all browsers.
 */
 sub, sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}
sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}
/* Embedded content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove border when inside `a` element in IE 8/9/10.
 */
 img {
    border: 0;
}
/**
 * Correct overflow not hidden in IE 9/10/11.
 */
 svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* Grouping content
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Address margin not present in IE 8/9 and Safari.
 */
 figure {
    margin: 1em 40px;
}
/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */
 hr {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    height: 0;
}
/**
 * Contain overflow in all browsers.
 */
 pre {
    overflow: auto;
}
/**
 * Address odd `em`-unit font size rendering in all browsers.
 */
 code, kbd, pre, samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace;
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Known limitation: by default, Chrome and Safari on OS X allow very limited
 * styling of `select`, unless a `border` property is set.
 */

/**
 * 1. Correct color not being inherited.
 *    Known issue: affects color of disabled elements.
 * 2. Correct font properties not being inherited.
 * 3. Address margins set differently in Firefox 4+, Safari, and Chrome.
 */
 button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    /* 1 */
    font: inherit;
    /* 2 */
    margin: 0;
    /* 3 */
}
/**
 * Address `overflow` set to `hidden` in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */
 button {
    overflow: visible;
}
/**
 * Address inconsistent `text-transform` inheritance for `button` and `select`.
 * All other form control elements do not inherit `text-transform` values.
 * Correct `button` style inheritance in Firefox, IE 8/9/10/11, and Opera.
 * Correct `select` style inheritance in Firefox.
 */
 button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
/**
 * 1. Avoid the WebKit bug in Android 4.0.* where (2) destroys native `audio`
 *    and `video` controls.
 * 2. Correct inability to style clickable `input` types in iOS.
 * 3. Improve usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type
 *    `input` and others.
 */
 button, html input[type="button"],
/* 1 */
 input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    /* 2 */
    cursor: pointer;
    /* 3 */
}
/**
 * Re-set default cursor for disabled elements.
 */
 button[disabled], html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}
/**
 * Remove inner padding and border in Firefox 4+.
 */
 button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/**
 * Address Firefox 4+ setting `line-height` on `input` using `!important` in
 * the UA stylesheet.
 */
 input {
    line-height: normal;
}
/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */
 input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Fix the cursor style for Chrome's increment/decrement buttons. For certain
 * `font-size` values of the `input`, it causes the cursor style of the
 * decrement button to change from `default` to `text`.
 */
 input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}
/**
 * 1. Address `appearance` set to `searchfield` in Safari and Chrome.
 * 2. Address `box-sizing` set to `border-box` in Safari and Chrome
 *    (include `-moz` to future-proof).
 */
 input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
/**
 * Remove inner padding and search cancel button in Safari and Chrome on OS X.
 * Safari (but not Chrome) clips the cancel button when the search input has
 * padding (and `textfield` appearance).
 */
 input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button, input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/**
 * Define consistent border, margin, and padding.
 */
 fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}
/**
 * 1. Correct `color` not being inherited in IE 8/9/10/11.
 * 2. Remove padding so people aren't caught out if they zero out fieldsets.
 */
 legend {
    border: 0;
    /* 1 */
    padding: 0;
    /* 2 */
}
/**
 * Remove default vertical scrollbar in IE 8/9/10/11.
 */
 textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}
/**
 * Don't inherit the `font-weight` (applied by a rule above).
 * NOTE: the default cannot safely be changed in Chrome and Safari on OS X.
 */
 optgroup {
    font-weight: bold;
}
/* Tables
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove most spacing between table cells.
 */
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td, th {
    padding: 0;
}
/********** MAIN STYLES **********/
 html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family:'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
* {
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.container {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 1.5%;
    margin: 2em;
    border: 3px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container-input {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
.list-section {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.shopping-header {
    text-align: center;
    background: lightgray;
}
.list-header {
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    color: #424242;
    background: #AEAEAE;
}
.cart-header {
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    color: #424242;
    background: #CC8E8E;
}
h1, h2 {
    font-family:'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1.15em;
}
button {
    font-family:'Hammersmith One', sans-serif;
}
.remove-from-list, .remove-from-cart, .text-input, .items, .cart-items {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.small-text {
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.75em;
}
.list-input {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
.button {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
}
.text-input {
    border: 1.5px solid black;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.button-input {
    width: 7em;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.list-items {
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.items, .cart-items {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.on-list {
    width: 45%;
    background: #dadada no-repeat;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.in-cart {
    width: 45%;
    background: #FFB2B2 no-repeat;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    padding: 5px;
    float: right;
}
.btns {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: small;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: none;
}
.btns-show {
    display: inline-block;
}
.add-to-cart, .remove-from-list {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.add-to-cart {
    color: blue;
    float: left;
}
.remove-from-list {
    color: red;
    float: right;
}
.remove-from-cart {
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: red;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.add-to-list {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
}
.cart {
    color: #5e5e5e;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    display: none;
}
.cart-show {
    display: inline-block;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.75rem;
    }
    .list-input, .button {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .button {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .button-input {
        width: 60%;
    }
    .on-list, .in-cart {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    h1 {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    .text-input, .button-input, .add-to-cart, .remove-from-list, .remove-from-cart {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .add-to-cart, .remove-from-list, .remove-from-cart {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .on-list, .in-cart {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }
    .container-input {
        border-top: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <section class="container">
  <header class="shopping-header">
   <h1>IN MY CART</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="small-text">Click 'ADD' button to add items to your list</div>
  <div class="container-input">
   <div class="list-input">
    <input type="text" class="text-input" name="list-name" placeholder="List Items..." value>
   </div>
   <div class="button">
    <button type="submit" class="button-input" name="list-button">ADD</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-section">
   <div class="on-list">
    <div class="list-header">My List</div>
    <div class="items"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="in-cart">
    <div class="cart-header">My Cart</div>
    <div class="cart-items"></div>
    <div class="remove-from-cart">Clear List</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: thanks for the help this does what I need to get done as well